# Are Labrador Retreiver typically stoic?

Tags: dogs

I have a neutered 2 y/o Male yellow lab. He constantly wants to be around the family and comes up on the couch like he is a lap dog. He comes up onto our bed every night. However, I don't often see him wagging his tail or licking the kids. He just likes to sit next to us and put his head on our lap.

This is very different from our 5 y/o German Shepherd who loves to give kisses and seems to be always wagging his tail. Is this just how Labs are? Are they sort of stoic?

I just want to make sure nothing is wrong with him.

Edit: Is it possible he is depressed?